# Subscription of observable returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, observable

I use a service to fill my observable with data from the backend. The backend is delievering the correct data. Now I want to take the values of the observable and build a piechart.

The part of the Code looks like this:

```
this.dataSet = this.dataService.getData(this.id);
this.dataSet.subscribe(
x => this.rightData = x.rightCount,
x => this.wrongData = x.wrongCount,
);
console.log('First value: '+ this.rightData);
console.log('Second value: '+ this.wrongData);
this.pieChartData = [this.rightData, this.wrongData];
```

It doesn't work and the console output is:

```
First Value: undefined
Second Value: undefined
```

But when I change the code to the following, the console log shows the right data:

```
this.dataSet = this.dataService.getData(this.id);
this.dataSet.subscribe( 
x => console.log(x.rightCount),
x => console.log(x,wrongCount),
);
```

Output:

```
3
7
```

Additional code:

```
export interface Counter {
  rightCount: number;
  wrongCount: number;
}

dataSet: Observable<Counter> = of();
```

The service looks like:

```
getData(id: number): Observable<Counter> {
    return this.http.get<Counter>(`/backend/getData?id=${id}`);
  }
```

The firefox log shows me, the backend returns:

```
{"rightCount":3,"wrongCount":7}
```

Do you have an Idea where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is normal since your code (subscribe) runs asynchronously. It would be the same as:

```
let test;
setTimeout(() => {this.test = "hello"}, 1000);
console.log(test);
```

The code above would print `undefined` right?

Doing `subscribe()` is similar to a `setTimeout` since both pieces of code runs asynchronously.

Also if you would do:

```
this.dataSet.subscribe(
    x => console.log('test1')
);
console.log('test2');
```

The output would be: `test2` `test1` because the code inside `subscribe` runs asynchronously

The correct code in your case would be:

```
this.dataService.getData(this.id).subscribe(
  x => {
    this.rightData = x.rightCount;
    console.log('First value: '+ this.rightData);
    // this.wrongData is undefined here
    this.pieChartData = [this.rightData, this.wrongData];
  },
  err => {
    this.wrongData = x.wrongCount;
    console.log('Second value: '+ this.wrongData);
    // this.rightData is undefined here
    this.pieChartData = [this.rightData, this.wrongData];
  }
);
```

please note that the Second value / wrongData will only occurr if an error is thrown in `this.dataService.getData`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I think I need better knowledge about asynchronous functions if I continue to work with angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the final manipulation inside the "finaly" in subscribe.

something like this

```
this.dataSet = this.dataService.getData(this.id);
this.dataSet.subscribe(
  x => (this.rightData = x.rightCount),
  x => (this.wrongData = x.wrongCount),
  () => {
    console.log('First value: ' + this.rightData)
    console.log('Second value: ' + this.wrongData)
    this.pieChartData = [this.rightData, this.wrongData]
  }
);
```

Or just

```
this.dataService.getData(this.id).subscribe(
  x => (this.rightData = x.rightCount),
  x => (this.wrongData = x.wrongCount),
  () => {
    console.log('First value: ' + this.rightData)
    console.log('Second value: ' + this.wrongData)
    this.pieChartData = [this.rightData, this.wrongData]
  }
);
```

Note that the "finally" doesn't receive any parameters, it only serves to do manipulations after receiving success or error from the observable